# Run programs from a different set path

Tags: nfs, path

I already read many of the ways to run a program when it is installed in a different address than the $PATH. I have a different problem.

On PC0, a set of packages (libraries and executables) were installed in the directory `/usr/local`. The problem lies in how to run these programs on PC1, which is connected in the network with PC0.

I thought about mounting this path (`/usr/local`) of PC0 on PC1 using NFS. But after doing this I'm stuck without knowing how to make my commands run knowing that the programs are now mounted in the `/media/NFS` directory.

Both PCs run on identical operating systems. But only one of them has the packages installed.
The solution of installing them in both is not useful because one lacks space in HDD.

Comment: What's the issue with adding the NFS mounted directory to `$PATH` (or more specifically, its `bin` subdirectory)?

Comment: Adding the NFS mounted directory to the $PATH is not a problem, I think!?!?
The problems is that even after do this, when I try to execute something, I receive a error message with "<some_file>.so" was not found

Comment: Ah, that's information that would be useful if you added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` would also need to be set to the location of the `*.so` files, presumably `/media/NFS/local/lib`, e.g. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/media/NFS/local/lib`.